# "Ambiguous occurrence" error even after a qualified import

Tags: haskell

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
import Control.Monad.State as S
get x = x + 1
```

Now if I try to use `get`, I get the following error:

```
Ambiguous occurrence `get'
It could refer to either `Main.get', defined at twitter.hs:59:1
                      or `S.get',
                         imported from Control.Monad.State at twitter.hs:15:1-31
```

Since I imported `Control.Monad.State` as a qualified module, shouldn't it automatically pick the `get` function in `Main`? Why is it running into this conflict? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use `import qualified Control.Monad.State as S`. Skipping `qualified` keyword brings into scope both `S.get` and `get`, etc.

> If the import declaration used the `qualified` keyword, only the `qualified` name of the entity is brought into scope. If the qualified keyword is omitted, then *both* the qualified *and* unqualified name of the entity is brought into scope.

See 5.3.2 and 5.3.4 of [Haskell 2010 report](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch5.html#x11-1010005.3).